# How to add Price Slider Filter in Layered Navigation on category Page. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sidebar, slider

I want to add a Slider filter (Scroller) on the SideBar currently My SideBar is 
[image]

but I want my Sidebar like
[image]
is there is any core functionality to change the price to this slider if **Yes** please let me know if **No** then let me know that how can I change this to Slider. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no core price slider functionality in Magento, you have to customize the functionality or you can use this module

https://www.magesolution.com/magento2-layered-navigation.html

Or if are using any premium theme then maybe the theme has the price slider functionality.